# Unwanted white space at the bottom of page

Tags: html, css, footer, removing-whitespace

I have unwanted space at bottom of the page. Cant figure out whats the problem.
I also searched for this tried every answer but no solutions

Comment: Welcome to SO - please visit the [help] to see how to ask questions

Comment: For a question like this, it would be best to include some of your code – ideally as little HTML and CSS as will allow us to reproduce the problem. Failing that, JSFiddle is a bit more permanent than a random URL. The goal is to phrase your question in a way that will help other people with the same problem to learn from your post later on (which won't be possible once you've fixed that URL!).

Comment: If you'd like to understand how people found the answers below, I'd recommend one of several free tutorials on [chrome developer tools](http://discover-devtools.codeschool.com).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's being caused by the length of the "Electrical equipment & parts" section of your product menu. You'll notice that the page height exactly matches the height of that part of the menu.

Also, in the 'Chemicals' section of the products menu, "Anti-Corrusions" is misspelled. "Anti-corrosion."

Answer (score 1):

Its the height from hidden sub menu from the nav.

Answer (score 0):

The first problem is that you have a `min-height: 800px` css rule set on your body tag -- get rid of that to start. The problem you'll have after that is that you want your footer to stick to the bottom of the page. You can do this by adding:

```
.blog-list-page {
  position: relative;
  min-height: 100%;
}

footer {
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  bottom: 0;
}
```